# How can I run Safari on playonlinux on Ubuntu 12.04? Direct3D9 is not available without OpenGL

Tags: wine, playonlinux, opengl

I have recently encounter a Problem when i run Safari web browser on Playonlinux in my Ubuntu 64 bit machine using command line,Safari runs but after 4-5 seconds some times more , i have got the message on vnc display that shows:
There Program safari.exe has encounter the Serious problem and need to be close we are sorry for inconvenience

Error in POL_Wine
Wine seems to have crashed.

And on terminal i saw

Direct3D9 is not available without OpenGL.

As i think this error has occur due to openGL is not install on my machine.
I am using Matrox Graphics card  and install driver such that
libdrm-dev
mesa-common-dev
libgl1-mesa-dev
but still getting the same error.
Does any one have any idea how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL libraries for DRM drivers are in the package `libgl1-mesa-glx` and you may also need `libglu1-mesa`, which depends on the former. Because Wine relies on 32-bit libraries, you need to install the package for i386 architecture:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa:i386
```

Alternatively you can install `wine` system-wide through the package manager instead of per user through POL. That will pull in the necessary libraries, since it depends on them:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

All the *-dev packages are unnecessary and can be uninstalled unless you want to compile software based on those libraries.

Comment: I have alredy install that package
And When i Run above Command i got the following.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgl1-mesa-glx is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 401 not upgraded

Comment: Ah sorry, you need the i386 libraries. See my update.

Comment: i hav already install that package. 


libx11-6:i386 is already the newest version.
libx11-6:i386 set to manually installed.

Comment: `libx11-6` doesn't contain libGL.so.1, but `libgl1-mesa-glx` does, as described in my answer. Did you install `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`?

Comment: Maybe Direct3D on Wine additionally needs libglu without explicitly saying so in its error message. At least the `wine` packages depend on it. See my update.

Comment: I have installed Matrox driver library. Now OpenGL error is not occuring but now Safari is not runing for a single second. A error message is flashed on my Vnc that Safari.exi has encounter a problem,Such that  Unhandled page fault on read access to 0xffffffff at address 0x7cb926a2 (thread 0009), starting debugger...
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0xffffffff in 32-bit code (0x7cb926a2).
any idea to resolve it.....

Comment: That's a separate issue and worthy of a new question. I fear it's a Wine bug though which would make it off topic here. Did you take a look at [Safari's Wine application database entry](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20398&iTestingId=81484)?

Answer (score 0):

Alright this is how I solve this. Open your safari first before doing anything, go to preference > Security > default space for database storage and increase db storage option to maximum ie 500mb.

[image: click here to see image]

Hope this'll help someone.